# How do I initialize values/data in a LineChart using Controllers?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, controller, fxml

I have an FXML file `chart.fxml` and a Controller class `Controller.java` for that FXML file. I wanted to make a **LineChart** using SceneBuilder, and initialize its data using a Controller.

However, when I run my program, the **LineChart** has no data/just shows the default LineChart.

This is my `Controller.java` class:

```
package exercise;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;

    void initData() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = initMap();
        NumberAxis x = new NumberAxis(
                map.entrySet().stream()
                        .min((p1, p2) -> p2.getKey() - p1.getKey())
                        .get()
                        .getKey(),
                map.entrySet().stream()
                        .min((p1, p2) -> p2.getKey() - p1.getKey())
                        .get()
                        .getValue(), 4
        );
        NumberAxis y = new NumberAxis();
        x.setLabel("Year");
        y.setLabel("Ranking");
        this.lineChart = new LineChart<>(x, y);
        this.lineChart.setTitle("Chart");

        XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
        data.setName("Ranks");
        map.forEach((key, value) -> data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(key, value)));

        lineChart.getData().add(data);
    }

    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> initMap() {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put(2007, 73);
        values.put(2008, 68);
        values.put(2009, 72);
        values.put(2010, 72);
        values.put(2011, 74);
        values.put(2012, 73);
        values.put(2013, 76);
        values.put(2014, 73);
        values.put(2015, 67);
        values.put(2016, 56);
        values.put(2017, 56);
        return values;
    }
}
```

This is my `Main` class:

```
package exercise;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/chart.fxml"));
        window.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initData();
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you mentioned the controller in the `fxml` file?

Comment: @AKSingh Yes, the fx:controller on my FXML file is set to `exercise.Controller`.

Comment: Don’t create a new `LineChart` in `initData()`. Just use the one injected from the FXML. If you need access to the axes, define those in the FXML and inject them to the controller too.

Comment: Add the fxml to the question formatted as code.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [all the duplicates listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721937/problem-loading-webpage-in-javafx-application-creating-simple-browser).

Comment: @James_D I see. Another question, the `NumberAxis` for my xAxis in my `LineChart` also accepts values for its constructor which are the lowerBound, upperBound, and tickUnit. How do I also set values for the NumberAxis constructor?

Comment: There's nothing special about it; just treat it the same way as everything else. Either in FXML: `<NumberAxis lowerBound="..." upperBound="..." tickUnit="..."/>` or do it in the `initialize()` method in the controller: `<NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis"/>` and `xAxis.setLowerBound(...);` etc.

Comment: @James_D I added the `lowerBound="2007"`, `upperBound="2017"`, and `tickUnit="4"` on my FXML file, but whenever I run try program, the line is fixed on a single position https://snipboard.io/ZEq3p4.jpg

Comment: With those bounds, you probably want `forceZeroInRange="false"` as well.

Comment: @James_D That fixed it. Thank you very much!